# Delta Lake Conversion on Databricks with Azure Data Lake Storage Throws FileAlreadyExistsException

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake, delta-lake

I'm trying to convert Parquet files to Delta format using Databricks and storing them in Azure Data Lake Storage. My process involves checking for an existing _delta_log directory and deleting it if found, before initiating the conversion. However, even when the _delta_log directory is not present, I'm getting a FileAlreadyExistsException.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def cleanup_delta_log(staging_path):
    delta_log_path = f"{staging_path}/_delta_log"
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    
    if spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()).exists(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(delta_log_path)):
        print(f"Deleting existing _delta_log at {delta_log_path}")
        spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()).delete(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(delta_log_path), True)

def process_table(table_name, source_name):
    staging_path = f"/mnt/landing/{source_name}/{table_name}/{table_name}"
    print(f"staging_path is {staging_path}")

    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(f"Processing_Table_{table_name}").getOrCreate()

    cleanup_delta_log(staging_path)
    
    spark.sql(f"CONVERT TO DELTA parquet.`{staging_path}`")

# Process tables...
```

Error message:

```
staging_path is /mnt/landing/source_name/tablename/tablename
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: Operation failed: "The specified path, or an element of the path, exists and its resource type is invalid for this operation.", ...
```

However, the following approach works:

```
df = spark.read.format("parquet").load(staging_path)
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(
    f"{source_name}.{source_name}_{table_name}"
)
```

I specifically want to avoid copying the data; I just want to add the _delta_log for Delta Lake conversion.

Things I've already verified:

- The _delta_log directory is not present before starting the conversion.
- I have the necessary permissions on the Azure Data Lake Storage.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any insights into why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried converting the parquet files to delta format in both cases, with and without **_delta_log**.
It did not give any error.

[image]

So, it is something related to deleting the file.
Try once restarting the cluster, and if you still face same error
you can use below approach.

```
import os
import shutil

directory_path = "/dbfs/<delta_path>/_delta_log"

if os.path.exists(directory_path):
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(directory_path)
        print(f"Directory '{directory_path}' has been deleted.")
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while deleting the directory: {e}")
else:
    print(f"Directory '{directory_path}' does not exist.")
    
spark.sql(f"CONVERT  TO  DELTA  parquet.`/mnt/landing/data/user1/user1/`")
spark.sql("select  *  from  delta.`/mnt/landing/data/user1/user1/`").show()
```

[image]

Or

```
path = [i[0] for i in dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/landing/data/user1/user1/") if  '_delta_log'  in i[0]]

if  len(path)>0:
    try:
        dbutils.fs.rm(path[0],True)
        print(f"Directory '{directory_path}' has been deleted.")
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while deleting the directory: {e}")
else:
    print(f"Directory '{directory_path}' does not exist.")
    
spark.sql(f"CONVERT  TO  DELTA  parquet.`/mnt/landing/data/user1/user1/`")
spark.sql("select  *  from  delta.`/mnt/landing/data/user1/user1/`").show()
```

[image]